# Geographical field points of a boundary

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geometry

I gathered field points with a TOPCON hand held receiver.  I saved the points as a shapefile and brought them into ArcMap.  I used the editor tool to connect the points and created a polygon.

Is there a tool that I can use within ArcMap to find the perimeter of the polygon?

Comment: Are you looking for the perimeter of the polygon?  You could always draw a polyline and easily get the distance of that (giving you the perimeter).

Comment: I drew the polygon but the attribute table is empty. I field shape file has all the points with the Northing, Eastings, and the Height value in the attribute table.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new field in the attribute table of the polygon. When you right-click on this new field, you will have the option to Calculate Geometry. Set the units appropriately and you're on your way.

Answer (score 1):

If you export the polygon shapefile to a Feature Class inside a File GDB, the "SHAPE_LENGTH" field should contain the perimeter based on the native unit of your coordinate system (e.g. meters for NAD 83, a useless Decimal Degree length for WGS 84, etc.).

[image: Shape Length]

@Chris's method above works too.

You can also manually measure the perimeter of the polygon using the [Measure Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/measuring-distances-and-areas.htm).